# Which lens should I buy Canon EF-S18-200mm f/3.5-5.6 IS Lens (Super Zoom Lens) or Tamron AF 18-200mm F/3.5-6.3 XR Di-II LD Aspherical (IF)?

Tags: lens, canon, tamron, canon-1100d

I am planning to buy a somewhat generic lens for all purpose. I am mostly into `group pictures`, `potraits` & `candid shots`. I found [Canon EF-S18-200mm f/3.5-5.6 IS Lens (Super Zoom Lens)](http://www.flipkart.com/canon-ef-s18-200mm-f-3-5-5-6-lens/p/itmczcrjfkweg2b8?pid=ACCCX3SGXXNXBXSN&_l=9PbncjCv5f7MRScGRufG0w--&_r=NKummzJb0SCLrexamjD26A--&ref=87776887-385b-42c5-a827-2680932dfa3d) suits a lot to what i shoot but the price is little high for me at the moment. So I found another lens from Tamron, [Tamron AF 18-200mm F/3.5-6.3 XR Di-II LD Aspherical (IF) Macro (for Canon Digital SLR) Lens (Macro Lens)](http://www.flipkart.com/tamron-af-18-200mm-f-3-5-6-3-xr-di-ii-ld-aspherical-if-macro-for-canon-digital-slr-lens/p/itmczckuyyv48zy8?pid=ACCCYNHKSWFXGRD8&_l=g3K0Y_l+_a37Rtm0plFKkA--&_r=NKummzJb0SCLrexamjD26A--&ref=cd6b9333-87a5-4e93-b125-4b38d3c2de0a).

Are these two lenses almost same?

If **yes**

> which 1 should I go for? Tamron lens is just half the price from canon

else

> help me with a suitable lens (generic lens) for Canon EOS 1100D

Below are a few things to consider before buying any lense

> **Money** as I am low on budget & photography is becoming a part of me
>
> I own a [Canon 1100D](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/canoneos1100D)
>
> To get a lens which can help me with **group photos, potraits & candid shot**.
>
> Better auto focus.

Please help me decide for a best lens. 
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered the Canon EFS 18-135? it gives you most of the zoom range of the 18-200 for a lower price - it is just as good as the 18-200 for group pictures, portraits (unless you have a big studio) and candid shots.

Comment: @Nir: Thanks for your comment. I'll go over some review.

Comment: The main *obvious* differences between the lenses are that the Tamron lacks Image stabilisation and only has f6.3 at the long end (which may slow your auto-focus).  Both of these mean that for distance shots, the canon probably has a noticable difference in usability.  How relevant that is will depend on how steady you are and where abouts in the zoom range you're likely to be shooting (as well as the likely light levels you'll be working in)...

Comment: @forsvarir: hmm that's a good point too (low light & stability) thanks

Comment: Some of these comments should be answers

Comment: I've "promoted" my comment to an answer after seeing Jakub's comment, @forsvarir should probably do the same

Answer (score 1):

What about [Tamron 18-270mm F/3.5 6.3 Di II VC PZD](http://www.flipkart.com/canon-ef-s18-200mm-f-3-5-5-6-lens/p/itmczcrjfkweg2b8?pid=ACCCX3SGXXNXBXSN&_l=9PbncjCv5f7MRScGRufG0w--&_r=NKummzJb0SCLrexamjD26A--&ref=87776887-385b-42c5-a827-2680932dfa3d) , it has more range and it is only marginally expensive ( in where you live ) than  [Canon EF-S18-200mm f/3.5-5.6 IS Lens (Super Zoom Lens)](http://www.flipkart.com/tamron-18-270mm-f-3-5-6-3-di-ii-vc-pzd-w-da-18-for-canon-digital-slr-lens/p/itmczc2hmfe6qk8j?pid=ACCCYZFNF8CDEBA8&_l=awxZStZHB3AVWEOmjtnlcw--&_r=NKummzJb0SCLrexamjD26A--&ref=f45edfec-c65a-41ad-9790-97da9bb2d24c). Apparently it gives same performance in 18-200 range and have 200-270 range in addition to that.

Comment: I got links mixed up. I apologize for that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the Canon EFS 18-135? it gives you most of the zoom range of the 18-200 for a lower price - it is just as good as the 18-200 for group pictures, portraits (unless you have a big studio) and candid shots.